# ¿Cómo sumar o restar solo días laborables en momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Estoy trabajando con fechas, y necesito calcular la diferencia entre dos días pero excluyendo los fines de semana.

Por ejemplo

si tengo

```
fecha_inicio: 05/03/2018
fecha_final: 13/03/2018
```

Debería obtener 7 días excluyendo los dias 10 y 11 que son sábado y domingo.

Lo trato de calcular con:

```
var inicio = moment(fecha_inicio);
var final = moment(fecha_final);
final.diff(inicio,"days");
```

Pero esto me devuelve 8.

¿Como podría solucionar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución seria ir revisando día a día y excluyendo los *sábados y domingos*

#### Demo

```js
function workingDays(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  var from = moment(dateFrom, 'DD/MM/YYY'),
    to = moment(dateTo, 'DD/MM/YYY'),
    days = 0;
    
  while (!from.isAfter(to)) {
    // Si no es sabado ni domingo
    if (from.isoWeekday() !== 6 && from.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
      days++;
    }
    from.add(1, 'days');
  }
  return days;
}


var days = workingDays('05/03/2018', '13/03/2018');
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Genial, me funcionó, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Trabajando en algo similar implementé una solución que les puede servir, en mi caso me funcionó:
(Este ejemplo arrojaría que en el rango de fechas hay 3 sábados y 3 domingos)

```js
var fecha_inicio = '17/04/2019';
var fecha_final = '8/05/2019';

inicio = moment(fecha_a);
fin = moment(fecha_b);
diferencia_dias = parseInt(fin.diff(inicio, 'days')) + parseInt(1); // Añadimos un dia mas para que cuente todos los dias incluyendo el inicial

num_dia = (parseInt(inicio.isoWeekday()));

for(i=1;i<=diferencia_dias;i++){
    if(num_dia == 6){
      alert('sabado');
      // Do something....
    }
    if(num_dia == 7){
      alert('domingo');
      num_dia=0;
      // Do something....
    }
    num_dia++;
  }
```

Seguramente se puede mejorar este código, pero básicamente con esto ya se puede empezar a controlar más cosas contando sábados y domingos.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*Con este se establece fechas de pago pero excluyendo los dias domingos, si el dia es domingo se le suma 1 al contador de domingos y se pone la fecha posterior USANDO MOMENT JS es facil*/

     for(let i=1;i<=cuotas;i++){
                 if(moment().add({'days':i+d}).format('dddd')==='domingo'){
                     d=d+1// OJO---->en esta variable se suma 1 cada ves que encuentra un domingo
                     newPago=new Pago({numero:i,fechaBono:moment().add({'days':i+d}),abono:cuotaAPagar})//creamos un pago asignandole el numero del contador
                     newPago.prestamo=newPrestamo//le asignamos en la propiedad prestamo de pago el objeto newPrestamo recien creado
                     newPago.save()//guardamos el nuevo pago

                     newPrestamo.pagos.push(newPago)//en el newPrestamo creado le pasamos al arreglo pagos el objeto newPago
                     await newPrestamo.save()//guardamos en newPrestamo

                 }else{
                    newPago=new Pago({numero:i,fechaBono:moment().add({'days':i+d}),abono:cuotaAPagar,fechaPagoAbono:moment().add({'days':i+d})})//creamos un pago asignandole el numero del contador
                    newPago.prestamo=newPrestamo//le asignamos en la propiedad prestamo de pago el objeto newPrestamo recien creado
                    newPago.save()//guardamos el nuevo pago

                    newPrestamo.pagos.push(newPago)//en el newPrestamo creado le pasamos al arreglo pagos el objeto newPago
                    await newPrestamo.save()//guardamos en newPrestamo
                 }

              }
```